# create custom score

Tags: android

I want to make a tennis score app but i don't know how to create a custom score (0, 15, 30, 40, advantage)?

Here is the code I've used with an other "counter" app:

```
public class counter extends Activity {

    // Private member field to keep track of the count
    private int Count = 0;


    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
        final Button countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

        countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Count++;
                countTextView.setText("" + Count);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: `countTextView.setText("" + Count);`

to:

```
If(Count == 1 || Count == 2){
  countTextView.setText("" + Count * 15);
} else if (Count ==3){
  countTextView.setText("" +40);
}else if (Count ==4){
  countTextView.setText("advantage");
} else {
  countTextView.setText("0");
}
```

And you shouldn't start variables with a capital either.

**CORRECTION**

```
lCount++;
if (lCount ==1){
countTextViewPlusL.setText("15");}
else
if (lCount ==2){
countTextViewPlusL.setText("30");}
else {
if (lCount ==3){
countTextViewPlusL.setText("40");}
else
if (lCount ==4){
countTextViewPlusL.setText("ad");}
else {
countTextViewPlusL.setText("0");
}
}
```